# Using drools for multiple object of same type and having relationships

Tags: java, drools, functor, rule-engine

Hey I have a following problem to solve using drools-

We have an Object-

```
Class Product{
 String name;
 double cost;
 double margin;
 double sellPrice;
}
```

We have a Product object-P1 and it can have multiple parents/relations of type Product lets say P1, P2, P3.... so on

Now the rule has to be like-

```
rule when: P1.cost<100
rule then: P1.sellPrice=P2.sellPrice+P3.sellPrice+.....
```

I am trying figure out a way/design to achieve this.

Comment: You'll have to add some Java code or similar so that we know how one Product P1 is related to those other Product objects. A Collection in Product, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I thing you can use the keyword collect, it allow you reason over collection from the given source, in this case every Product inserted in the working memory (less product who is being evaluated )

I hope this piece of code can guide you:

```
    rule "Sum sellPrice's property Product if Product's cost < 100"
    no-loop
        when
            $p : Product(cost<100) 
            $items : java.util.List(size > 0) //execute rule if list.size > 0
                    from collect( Product(name != $p.name) )    //create list from each Product less this ($p)  
        then
            double totalSellPrice = 0;
            Product p = null;
            for(Object item: $items)
            {
                p = (Product)item;
                totalSellPrice += p.getSellPrice();
            }
            //finally modify product who is being evaluated
            modify($p){setSellPrice(totalSellPrice)};
    end
```

This post explain who collect (from and accumulate) works http://blog.athico.com/2007/06/chained-from-accumulate-collect.html

Comment: Thanks, I have one question can accumulate be used in Then part of rule?

Comment: `accumulate` is for the LHS, not the RHS. It's worth noting that if you write a custom accumulator, you can sum everything up in the LHS in a reactive fashion. For instance, the sell price can decrease if a product is removed, instead of recalculating the sum for the whole list every time the list is changed.

Comment: @Steve Not necessarily a *custom* accumulator. The accumulate CE with count and sum works out of the box.

Comment: This answer (obviously induced by the imprecise question) is built on a very unlikely scenario. Given that all Product facts are equally likely to match the first CE `Product(cost<100)`, the rule may fire multiple times, each time updating another such Product from the set of all other Product, which includes those that have been updated before. It is hard to imagine a situation where this is required. And I agree with Steve: an accumulate CE is preferable to collect - it also eliminates the need for iterating to calculate the sum on the right hand side. - All in all, not the answer I'd accept

Comment: I agree, after reading your comments I don't think my answer is the correct answer. Please @AashishKatta uncheck my answer as correct answer. It is difficult imagine the scenario, anyway, use accumulate is better approach.